# Flex 4 - Which event is useful for form validation Except Button Click?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have done the **Form validation** for a **Button Click**. But I want to know the better event for the same Form validation. Because I have to change the Button enabled property value before and after the From validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate a field one by one after [focusOut (Adobe Docs reference)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html)-event fires and set the Button enabled property to true after all fields have been properly validated.

Comment: yes I done it. Thank you so much for your answer and for the link. This link is also useful to know about the Focus event.